# Android dropdown button

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, android-spinner, material-design

What is this [dropdown button](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B3321sZLoP_HTS1LdnhrTl9TRzg/components-buttons-otherbuttons-060203_MobileDropdowns_xhdpi_006.webm)? It looks like a spinner and the animation can be found [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-other-buttons).

I tried using spinner but it's not the same. This one looks awesome! Can anybody help me find it? I need to create something similar.

Answer (score 3):

If the [Spinner on Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) does not fit your needs, maybe you could try

1. [rey5137/material - Spinner](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Spinner)
2. [ganfra/MaterialSpinner](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner)

With the following code on [rey5137/material - Spinner](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Spinner), you could create the spinner with ripple effect.

```
    <com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
        style="@style/Material.Widget.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:rd_style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave"/>
```

Comment: Link-only answers are **deprecated**

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a material Spinner. It looks like on the image below. If you like it, it's available as a part of Carbon library. You can find it here: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon

[image]